# How to avoid repeating property projections when using EF Core inheritance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling with how to avoid repeating projection logic when using [inheritance in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).

Here's my scenario: I have three types:

1. `Lesson` (which is an abstract class) (Properties: `Id`, `Title`, etc.)
2. `ArticleLesson` (which inherits from `Lesson`) (Properties: `Content`, `TotalWoddsCount`, etc.)
3. `VideoLesson` (which inherits from `Lesson`) (Properties: `VideoUrl`, `Duration`, etc.)

Almost everything is handled properly by EF Core, and I'm using the default Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) approach.

The problem arises when I want to retrieve lessons from the database and I need some of the shared columns between `ArticleLesson` and `VideoLesson` (i.e. some of the properties of `Lesson`), PLUS, some of the properties specific to either `ArticleLesson` or `VideoLesson`. Here's the expression I've come up with:

```cs
var r1 = dbContext.Lessons.Select<Lesson, LessonDto>(l =>
    l is ArticleLesson
    ? new ArticleLessonDto
    {
        Id = l.Id, // This is repeated below
        Title = l.Title, // This is repeated below
        // ...other properties that I would have to repeat below
        Content = (l as ArticleLesson).Content,
    }
    : l is VideoLesson
    ? new VideoLessonDto
    {
        Id = l.Id, // This is repeated above
        Title = l.Title, // This is repeated above
        // ...other properties that I would have to repeat above
        VideoUrl = (l as VideoLesson).VideoUrl,
    }
    : null
)
.ToList();
```

As you can see, I'm repeating the shared properties part, twice. There are just 2 properties that are being repeated in this example, `Id` and `Title`, but in the real world you can have dozens of these; and having to repeat all of them like this would be a h.

Is there any way to make this projection expression more succinct and avoid the repetition?

Comment: Short answer: efforts for such implementation will be high. Better to copy/paste in this one place. If you have a tons of such cases, collect them and create new question.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a constructor to your `LessonDto`, `ArticleLessonDto` and `VideoLessonDto` that accepts the different shared properties.

```cs
    public class LessonDto
    {
        public LessonDto(int id, ... other)
        {
            Id = id;
            // ...
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArticleLessonDto : LessonDto
    {
        public ArticleLessonDto(LessonDto dto) : base(dto.Id)
        {

        }

        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    var r1 = dbContext.Lessons
        .Select(l => new
        {
            dto = new LessonDto(l.Id, ... other),
            full = l
        })
        .Select(row => row.full is ArticleLesson
        ? new ArticleLessonDto(row.dto)
        {
            Content = (row.full as ArticleLesson).Content,
        }
        : row.full is VideoLesson
        ? new VideoLessonDto(row.dto)
        {
            VideoUrl = (row.full as VideoLesson).VideoUrl,
        }
        : (LessonDto)null
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, passing `l` to the constructor of `ArticleLessonDto` or `VideoLessonDto` (or also passing it to any unrecognized methods, for that matter) will cause EF Core to retrieve all the columns of that row from the database; which is inefficient.

Comment: @Arad sorry, I missed that requirement. To reduce the bandwidth, just have a constructor that accepts the required shared parameters. I updated my answer for this scenario. (verified with SQL Server provider)

Comment: Well, it's again the same story, you've ended up repeating the shared properties twice, once for `VideoLessonDto` and once for `ArticleLessonDto` ; which was the very thing that we wanted to avoid in the first place :(

Comment: @Arad it was actually a 50% reducement of code, since you did not have to repeat all the assignments. but hey - there's a solution for this as well. updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out. I hope the new updated version doesn't cause all columns to be retrieved, though. But it's clever nevertheless.

Comment: @Arad verified in SqlServer provider, should probably work in others as well