# Is there a way to use C# 9.0 conditional expressions in a C# 7.3 project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Found a nice way to use a projection for the inherided classes of an abstract class
[How to avoid repeating property projections when using EF Core inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322631/how-to-avoid-repeating-property-projections-when-using-ef-core-inheritance)

```
var r1 = dbContext.Lessons.Select<Lesson, LessonDto>(l =>
    l is ArticleLesson
        ? new ArticleLessonDto
        {
            Id = l.Id, // This is repeated below
            Title = l.Title, // This is repeated below
            // ...other properties that I would have to repeat below
            Content = (l as ArticleLesson).Content,
        }
        : l is VideoLesson
            ? new VideoLessonDto
            {
                Id = l.Id, // This is repeated above
                Title = l.Title, // This is repeated above
                // ...other properties that I would have to repeat above
                VideoUrl = (l as VideoLesson).VideoUrl,
            }
            : null
)
```

The problem is that works in C# 9.0 only which requires dotnet 5.
The project I am working on is running on dotnet 4.7 and C# 7.3 and it is not my decision to change that.
The main difference to the linked code above is that I need an IQueryable<> that means I cannot use .ToList() or anything that would materialize the query.

I have tried to extract the condition as expression and extension method but EF tries to convert that to SQL which will of course fail.

```
public static Expression<Func<Lesson, LessonDto>> CreateLessonDto = l => l.CreateLessonDto();

public static LessonDto CreateLessonDto(this Lesson Lesson)
{
    if (Lesson is ArticleLesson)
        return new ArticleLessonDto();
    else if (Lesson is VideoLesson)
        return new VideoLessonDto();

    return null;
}

var r1 = dbContext.Lessons.Select(CreateLessonDto);
```

Using .OfType<> and Union does not seem to work either.

Any ideas how to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In the first example, I don't see C# 9 specific syntax. Maybe the problem is EF 6 vs EF Core 5. Can you confirm the version of Entity Framework you use?

Comment: @vernou tagged and using EF6. The ? : in a select is C# 9 since the condition returns different types https://web.archive.org/web/20210807210937/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression

Comment: Wait.. you think that nested ternary construct is nice?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for such task. It will simplify building such extensions.

You have to instruct LINQKit how to inject your projections into Expression Tree.

```cs
[Expandable(nameof(CreateLessonDtoImpl))]
public static LessonDto CreateLessonDto(this Lesson Lesson) 
   => throw new NotImplementedException();

private static Expression<Func<Lesson, LessonDto>> CreateLessonDtoImpl()
{
    return l => l is ArticleLesson
        ? ((ArticleLesson)l).CreateArticleLessonDto()
        : l is VideoLesson
            ((VideoLesson)l).CreateVideoLessonDto()
            : null;
}

// helpers

[Expandable(nameof(CreateArticleLessonDtoImpl))]
public static ArticleLessonDto CreateArticleLessonDto(this ArticleLesson Lesson) 
   => throw new NotImplementedException();

private static Expression<Func<ArticleLesson, ArticleLessonDto>> CreateArticleLessonDtoImpl()
{
    return l => new ArticleLessonDto
    {
        Id = l.Id, // This is repeated below
        Title = l.Title, // This is repeated below
        // ...other properties that I would have to repeat below
        Content = l.Content,
    };
}

[Expandable(nameof(CreateVideoLessonDtoImpl))]
public static VideoLessonDto CreateVideoLessonDto(this VideoLesson Lesson) 
   => throw new NotImplementedException();

private static Expression<Func<VideoLesson, VideoLessonDto>> CreateVideoLessonDtoImpl()
{
    return l => new VideoLessonDto
    {
        Id = l.Id, // This is repeated below
        Title = l.Title, // This is repeated below
        // ...other properties that I would have to repeat below
        VideoUrl = l.VideoUrl,
    };
}
```

And usage in queries:

```cs
var r1 = dbContext.Lessons
   .AsExpandable() // important
   .Select(l => l.CreateLessonDto());
```

This approach has several benefits:

- You can reuse these methods in other queries
- It generates effective SQL
- Can be used not only for projections

For EF Core, `LINQKit` have simplified it's usage and there is no longer needed to use `AsExpandable()` call in queries. You can just specify `WithExpressionExpanding` when building `DbContextOptions`

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. Unfortunately I cannot test it right now since I am working on a different problem. Will give it a try as soon as possible. The first private static should be CreateLessonDtoImpl, right?

Comment: Yeah, will correct. Writing from memory ;)