# Call method in Linq Select() without loading whole object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following code using .NET 5 and EF Core:

```cs
IQueryable<ExampleViewModel> list = query.Select(x => new ExampleViewModel()
{
  Id = x.Id,
  BindDate = x.BindDate,
  CancellationDate = x.CancellationDate,
  ChangeDate = x.ChangeDate,
  CreateDate = x.CreateDate,
  Description = x.Description,
  PrimaryOffice = x.PrimaryOffice == null
        ? null
        : new GenericComboBox()
        {
          Value = x.PrimaryOffice.Id,
          Text =x.PrimaryOffice.LocationName
          + (x.PrimaryOffice.LocationBusinessName == null ? "" : " (" + x.PrimaryOffice.LocationBusinessName + ") ")
          + "("
          + (x.PrimaryOffice.AddressLine1 != null ? x.PrimaryOffice.AddressLine1 + ", " : null)
          + (x.PrimaryOffice.AddressLine2 != null ? x.PrimaryOffice.AddressLine2 + ", " : null)
          + (x.PrimaryOffice.City != null ? x.PrimaryOffice.City + ", " : null)
          + (x.PrimaryOffice.State != null ? x.PrimaryOffice.State.Name != null ? x.PrimaryOffice.State.Name + ", " : null : null)
          + (x.PrimaryOffice.ZipCode ?? null)
          + ")"
        }   
});
```

The query you see for PrimaryOffice is going to be used for several more objects just as it is. 100% same. So I want to move the query after the

> PrimaryOffice =

to method so I can re use it easy. So far so good.
The problem is I cant simply create method which takes x.PrimaryOffice as param and return PrimaryOffice  class ( GenericComboBox ), because that will load my whole 'x' object.

This is NOT an option:

```cs
public static GenericComboBox GenericComboBoxCreate(AddressObj x)
{
  if (x != null)
  {
    return new GenericComboBox()
    {
      Value = x.Id,
      Text = x.LocationName
        + ( x.LocationBusinessName == null ? "" : " (" + x.LocationBusinessName + ") " )
        + "("
        + ( x.AddressLine1 != null ? x.AddressLine1 + ", " : null )
        + ( x.AddressLine2 != null ? x.AddressLine2 + ", " : null )
        + ( x.City != null ? x.City + ", " : null )
        + ( x.State != null ? x.State.Name != null ? x.State.Name + ", " : null : null )
        + ( x.ZipCode ?? null )
        + ")"
    };
  }

  return null;
}
```

And then:

```cs
PrimaryAgencyOffice = SomeHelper.GenericComboBoxCreate(x.PrimaryOffice)
```

I use Odata and I need to take from the DB only the properties I really need.
Because If I use the method above EF loads EVERYTHING and the query is far from optimal.

I think some method with `Expression<Func< , >>` should be the solution but I can`t figure it out so far.

If it was about the WHOLE Select() statement that would be easy. But it is about one property in the Select.

I guess some method with `Expression<Func<AgencyAddress, GenericComboBox>>` as param and return type GenericComboBox?

Comment: You have to deal with expressions. For method substitution to Expression. Check this [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68804384/10646316) It is almost the same that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need a helper method to format your `GenericComboBox.Text`. How about a static utility method to do so?

```cs
public static string GetAddressString(string locationName, string locationBusinessName, string addressLine1, string addressLine2, string city, string state, string zip)
{
    string txt = "{0}{1}({2}{3}{4}{5}{6})";
    locationBusinessName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationBusinessName) ? string.Empty : string.Format(" ({0})", locationBusinessName);
    addressLine1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(addressLine1) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", addressLine1);
    addressLine2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(addressLine2) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", addressLine2);
    city = string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", city);
    state = string.IsNullOrEmpty(state) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", state);
    zip = string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", zip);
    return string.Format(
                txt, 
                locationName,
                locationBusinessName, 
                addressLine1,
                addressLine2,
                city,
                state,
                zip
            );
}
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```cs
IQueryable<ExampleViewModel> list = query.Select(x => new ExampleViewModel()
{
  .  .  .  .

  PrimaryOffice = x.PrimaryOffice == null ? null : new GenericComboBox()
  {
      Value = x.PrimaryOffice.Id, 
      Text = SomeHelper.GetAddressString(
          x.PrimaryOffice.LocationName,
          x.PrimaryOffice.LocationBusinessName,
          x.PrimaryOffice.AddressLine2, 
          x.PrimaryOffice.City, 
          x.PrimaryOffice.State ? x.PrimaryOffice.State.Name: string.Empty,
          x.PrimaryOffice.ZipCode
       )
    } 
});
```

You can even put the `GetAddressString` method inside your `PrimaryOffice` class:

```
public class PrimaryOffice {
    //... your properties....
    
    public string GetAddressString()
    {
        string txt = "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}";
        string locationBusinessName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LocationBusinessName) ? string.Empty : string.Format(" ({0})", this.LocationBusinessName);
        string addressLine1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AddressLine1) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", this.AddressLine1);
        string addressLine2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AddressLine2) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", this.AddressLine2);
        string city = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.City) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", this.City);
        string state = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.State) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", this.State.Name);
        string zip = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Zip) ? string.Empty : string.Format(", {0}", this.Zip);
        return string.Format(
            txt, 
            this.LocationName,
            locationBusinessName, 
            addressLine1,
            addressLine2,
            city,
            state,
            zip
        );
    }
}
```

Then just access it like:

```
  PrimaryOffice = x.PrimaryOffice == null ? null : new GenericComboBox()
  {
      Value = x.PrimaryOffice.Id, 
      Text = x.PrimaryOffice.GetAddressString()
  }
```

**OR** you could add a custom Getter for something like `PrimaryOfficeName` in your `PrimaryOffice` class:

Comment: The first solution is working (method with several params) Thanks!. However, the second approach (GetAddressString method inside PrimaryOffice class) still loads whole object and makes big query to the DB. I wonder why

Comment: @Jackie, glad I was able to help. Please mark this as accepted answer if you are satisfied. I also updated the code to `x.PrimaryOffice.State ? x.PrimaryOffice.State.Name: string.Empty` instead of `x.PrimaryOffice.State ?? x.PrimaryOffice.State.Name`.

Comment: It is valid answer, I will await a bit for better one. Can u explain why the second approach is invalid?

Comment: It is not OK. When using Odata orderby (by the complex property) EF throws exception it cannot translate the query.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for such task.

Enable extension while building options:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Implement your method in the following way:

```cs
[Expandable(nameof(GenericComboBoxCreateImpl))]
public static GenericComboBox GenericComboBoxCreate(this AddressObj x)
    => throw new NotImplementedException();

private static Expression<Func<AddressObj, GenericComboBox>> GenericComboBoxCreateImpl()
{
  return x => x == null ? null :
    new GenericComboBox()
    {
      Value = x.Id,
      Text = x.LocationName
        + ( x.LocationBusinessName == null ? "" : " (" + x.LocationBusinessName + ") " )
        + "("
        + ( x.AddressLine1 != null ? x.AddressLine1 + ", " : null )
        + ( x.AddressLine2 != null ? x.AddressLine2 + ", " : null )
        + ( x.City != null ? x.City + ", " : null )
        + ( x.State != null ? x.State.Name != null ? x.State.Name + ", " : null : null )
        + ( x.ZipCode ?? null )
        + ")"
    };
}
```

And benefits from usage:

```cs
IQueryable<ExampleViewModel> list = query.Select(x => new ExampleViewModel()
{
  Id = x.Id,
  BindDate = x.BindDate,
  CancellationDate = x.CancellationDate,
  ChangeDate = x.ChangeDate,
  CreateDate = x.CreateDate,
  Description = x.Description,
  PrimaryOffice = x.PrimaryOffice.GenericComboBoxCreate()
});
```